# Creating a database for Joomla! installed locally

Tags: joomla-3.4

I'm absolutely new to Joomla!. I followed the instructions to install XAMPP and Joomla! 3.4.3 and everything worked. I used XAMPP's phpmyadmin to create a  new database and then during Joomla! installation I just referred to the name of that database. 
Would it be the same if I hadn't created a database using XAMPP? I mean, if during Joomla! installation I typed an arbitrary name for a database, would it be created for me? Or is creating a database using XAMPP beforehand and then referring to this database during the installation important? 
I am really sorry if question is not specific enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience, you usually don't need to create the database first **on localhost environments** (XAMPP, WAMP etc) when installing Joomla. Simply use `root` as user, leave the password field empty (the root user password is empty by default), and type in any database name (make sure it doesn't exist already). The database will be created automatically if it doesn't exist, and the root user has all required permission for Joomla to work.

XAMPP and other similar software install with reduced security settings by default because they are not meant to be run on a live server, only in local environments for development purposes.

Obviously, when you transfer your Joomla site to a live server, you'll have to set up the database and database user *before* installing Joomla.

Answer (score 5):

You must always create your database for before installing Joomla and then refer to it in the installation settings. This is a requirement.

Joomla will never create the *database* and *database user* for you on installation as this is a potential security risk.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. The reason why I decided to ask is that many Joomla! installation tutorials don't even mention the necessity to  set up a database before installing Joomla!.For example, http://www.insquaremedia.com/joomla-guides/11-building-a-joomla-site/19-how-to-install-joomla-on-xampp

Comment: Yup thats fair enough. Was a good question to ask. You go my upvote ;)

Comment: You got mine too! I really don't want to seem stupid,I'm rather curious: why are there different opinions on that? Some people say that it's absolutely obligatory to have a database beforehand while some say that Joomla! has all the rights to create one during installation and I just have to type in my username (usually:root) and leave the password form blank.

Comment: Ahh I have just made a test using the description that @johan provided. Yes it does work, *however*, please read **Level 4 (Webmaster)** from the section on Joomla documentation page: https://docs.joomla.org/Security_and_Performance_FAQs#How_do_I_setup_a_powerful_password_scheme.3F